# Twig "Is defined" throwing error on matrix row EntryModel property

Tags: templating, matrix, defined

When checking if a matrix block property is defined, I'm getting an error:

```
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "contentSource".
```

The line that is throwing this error is specifically checking if that property is defined.

```
{% if block.contentSource is defined %}
    {# Stuff and things #}
{% endif %}

-- Or --

{% set theThing = block.contentSource ?? "fallback" %}
```

Am I expecting the "is defined" check to be smarter than it actually is? I can't see an example of this in the matrix field or craft twig/templating docs.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey James, try `block['contentSource']` instead or test against an attribute rather than a field, e.g. `if block.type == 'foo'`.

Comment: See answers in the link above.